# Convert raw html to text with javascript and regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have raw html with link tags and the goal I want to achieve is extract href attribute from  tags and all text between tags except  tags.
For example:

```
<br>#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="1377",Страшное HD<br>
<a title="Ссылка" rel="nofollow" href="http://4pda.ru/pages/go/?u=http%3A%2F%2F46.61.226.18%2Fhls%2FCH_C01_STRASHNOEHD%2Fbw3000000%2Fvariant.m3u8%3Fversion%3D2" target="_blank">http://46.61.226.18/hl…variant.m3u8?version=2</a>
<br>#EXTINF:-1  tvg-name="983" ,Первый канал HD<br>
<a title="Ссылка" rel="nofollow" href="http://4pda.ru/pages/go/?u=http%3A%2F%2F46.61.226.18%2Fhls%2FCH_C06_1TVHD%2Fbw3000000%2Fvariant.m3u8%3Fversion%3D2" target="_blank">http://46.61.226.18/hl…variant.m3u8?version=2</a>
```

have to convert to:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="1377",Страшное HD
http://4pda.ru/pages/go/?u=http%3A%2F%2F46.61.226.18%2Fhls%2FCH_C01_STRASHNOEHD%2Fbw3000000%2Fvariant.m3u8%3Fversion%3D2
#EXTINF:-1  tvg-name="983" ,Первый канал HD
http://4pda.ru/pages/go/?u=http%3A%2F%2F46.61.226.18%2Fhls%2FCH_C06_1TVHD%2Fbw3000000%2Fvariant.m3u8%3Fversion%3D2
```

I tried different regex's:

Here what I did

1. `var source_text = $("#source").val();`
2. `var delete_start_of_link_tag = source_text.replace(/<a(.+?)href="/gi, "");`

   - delete beginning of the  tag to the href attribute
3. `var delete_tags = delete_start_of_link_tag.replace(/<\/?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>/gi, "");`

   - delete all tags `</a>`, `<br>`

[example](http://codepen.io/vborshchov/pen/pjyOvP)

And then I want to delete all text after href values to the end of the line.

**What regex should i use in replace method or maybe where is a some different way to do this converting?**

Comment: Do you want to include text of sibling elements or just sibling text nodes? In your question you only show sibling text nodes, no text inside a `<span>` for example. Also, do you want to modify the elements on the page, or only extract a copy of the text?

Comment: I want user puts text (which include some html tags - html in text format) in the textarea on the web page and then click button "convert". As a result the user must get extracted text in the other textarea on the same web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Formatting Anchor Tags**

In your example , you are not replacing the `">` part form the html.
So check this [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyqdYK)

use this code to remove everything after href close quote(' or ")

```
var delete_tags = delete_start_of_link_tag.replace(/".*/gi, "");
```

And few things to notice are
1.The value in `href` is enclosed in single quote(`'`) or  double quotes(`"`), both are valid.
2.The exact regex to match all `href` in a given string or content is `href=[\"|'].*?[\"|']`
3.Some patterns in `href` values , I came across are below.

- `http://www.so.com`
- `https://www.so.com`
- `www.so.com`
- `//so.com`
- `/socom.html`
- `javascript*`
- `mailto*`
- `tel*`

So if you want to format URL's then you have consider the above cases and i may have missed some.

Comment: Your answer prompted me to solve the problem. Here it is [codepen](http://codepen.io/vborshchov/pen/pjyOvP). This is one-regex-solution.

Comment: Your character class should be this instead: `["']([^"']*)["']`. Pipes (`|`) mean nothing inside a character class and will literally be matched inside them. And double quotes don't need to be escaped in regex. Plus, the best way to match until a certain character is using a negated character class, or `[^"]` (meaning match anything besides a quote).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're already using jQuery.

Get the href of each anchor

```
$('a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Get the text of each anchor:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
});
```

You haven't shown a wrapper element around these but you can get the text (without tags) of any selection.

```
var text = $('#some_id').text();
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/u009ojwm/)

Comment: I think I did not explain clearly. I want some specific text which I paste into textarea to be converter to another text without certain symbols. I updated question's _example link_ (but now this example did not work properly)